# Customizing tray/taskbar date display in Ubuntu with GNOME 3

Tags: gnome-shell, system-tray, clock

On previous versions I had the date displayed. Now it just shows the current day but not the day's number or the month.

Is there a way to customize the clock or tray/taskbar more in GNOME shell on Ubuntu 17.10 and later?

Comment: I installed gnome-tweak-tool that did the trick with the clock. Might check out the shell extension at some point. The only other thing I'm missing is compiz cube rotation. I'm not sure how to get the workspace switcher button back. ctrl alt left or right doesn't switch the workspace.

Comment: If you dont want to install any new software use this to write to the gnome config: ```dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/clock-show-date 'true' ```

Comment: similar to @psykid's suggestion. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-weekday true`

Answer (score 377):

You can get the date displayed in the top bar by using `gnome-tweaks` (was `gnome-tweak-tool`). First open up a terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and install the tweak tool with

```bash
# sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool # obsolete package
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks # current package
gnome-tweaks  #  now launch it
```

After that you can start it from the application selector (there the name is just tweaks) and navigate inside the tweak tool to the tab for 'Top Bar' and activate Date and Seconds (see screen-shot).

[image]

Although this might be the easiest approach for the casual user there's another method which works. By issuing the following terminal command you can set the same:

```bash
# makes the date appear
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true
# switches the seconds display on
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
```

By replacing `set` with `get` you can ask the system to give you the actual settings. Example:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds
```

Comment: `gnome-tweak-tool` is really an essential package for anyone who is actually _using_ their computers for more than 5 minutes.

Comment: It's worth noting that once installed, the name of the application is Tweaks.

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: I've just upgraded to 18.04 (and lost all settings again). I've installed gnome-tweak-tool but there is no "Top Bar" tab

Comment: The date should be shown by default beside the clock. (Who needs to know the day of the week without also knowing the date!!). The fact that you have to install an extra package to enable it is unfathomable!

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 18.04 too. Thank you.

Comment: @EoghanM Installing an extra package is actually not necessary, you can turn this on by just running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true`. (Videonauth, please consider adding the `gsettings`/`dconf` method to the answer.)

Comment: @pomsky done so.

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true` doesn't work for me, and gnome-tweak-tool doesn't have a "Top Bar" tab. Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Available in the software center as "Gnome Tweaks"

Answer (score 31):

For a more granular control, you may use the [**Clock override**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/) GNOME shell extension (reference: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481)). With it, you can

> Customize the date and time format displayed in clock in the top bar in GNOME Shell. Add as much or as little time information you want with extensive formatting options including an emoji clock face and Internet Time (.beat).

It supports [Python's `strftime` format](http://strftime.org/).

Extension homepage: https://github.com/stuartlangridge/gnome-shell-clock-override

Comment: This Clock Override extension is AWESOME: it gives you complete freedom to customise the clock the way you want. Be prepared to read up the syntax for the format string though, unless you know it already from Python.

Comment: edit format to show just date and time   `%F %R`

Comment: This is great, but now it doesn't have enough space to display the full date&time. My setting is `%a %e %b %y %H:%M` and it display's only: `Sat 25 j ...`. Is there a way to increase the area of the display size?