# Customizing tray/taskbar date and time in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04

In Ubuntu 16.04 we used to see date displayed.

[image: 16.04 tray]

Also, we could see the seconds ongoing.

In 18.04, I can't find any settings that could help me to see the seconds and date in the task bar.

[image: 18.04]

Comment: I got the solution. Try the Tweaks app after installation.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/966576/customizing-tray-taskbar-date-display-in-ubuntu-17-10