# Time and date is missing on top bar of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, system-tray, clock

Time and date is not available any more on top bar after I upgraded Ubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04 LTS. Time&Date settings is not available in "Settings", and it's not available in gnome-tweak-tool either(there's no "Top bar" menu in tweak GUI):

[image: screen shot]

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966634/312460) works for me (install gnome tweak tool and enable date in top bar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing tray/taskbar date display in Ubuntu beginning with 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966576/customizing-tray-taskbar-date-display-in-ubuntu-beginning-with-17-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've logged into a Unity session somehow. If that is not intended, you may want to login to a GNOME session (default in 18.04).

To do that when you boot your system and get to the GDM login screen you should find a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button. If you click on the cogwheel you should find an *Ubuntu* (and *Ubuntu on Wayland*) option. Select it and log in.

Comment: Yes, date&time shows up normally in middle of the top bar after logging in to "Ubuntu". Unity must have been the default session for some reason and I totally forgot to switch it to GNOME through the cogwheel. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: It's the other way around for me: it works fine with Unity but with Gnome I had to install a third party software to display the date and time...