# Change mouse speed on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, 18.04, mouse

This is one of various DE issues I am struggling with since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. After a couple of days I started feeling some pain in my right wrist. I now realise the mouse speed was reduced in the upgrade and thus I am no longer able to move the pointer from one edge of the screen to another in a single movement. I have tried to tweak mouse speed in the *Settings* > *Mouse & Touchpad* dialogue, like I used to do in previous Ubuntu releases:

[image]

This however, has no effect. The pointer speed seems to be stuck at the middle, ignoring whatever is displayed in the dialogue.

Is there any other way of changing mouse speed on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: @pa4080 I tried unplug and plug again, but it has no effect.

Comment: Unity still use synapric drivers. Since touchpad settings is missing fro  your settings you probably using libinput and don't have synaptic installed. Though mouse pointer should still work. And it works for me. So may be some driver issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change mouse speed/sensitivity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
xinput --set-prop 11 294 1
```

where:

11: is my mouse id, you should find and replace with yours

```
xinput --list --short
```

294: is the "Accel Speed" property id of my mouse. Just change 11 with your id and you can find your desired prop id with

```
xinput --list-props 11
```

1: the final number is the property value. For me default was 0, 1 accelerated the pointer up.

You can add the first command to the startup applications to keep the settings after a reboot. Instead of the device and prop id you can quote them in case they change after a reboot, ex:

```
xinput --set-prop 'Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse' 'libinput Accel Speed' 1
```

Source and more details taken from here:
[How to change mouse speed/sensitivity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205676)

Comment: Note that mouse speed is reset to zero when the session is closed. I had to add a script to the Startup Applications that runs `xinput`.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa You are right, I updated my answer. For me worked without a script, I added just the command to the startup applications.

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS MISLEADING!!!!

Answer (score 5):

To solove the problem of "I'm using a 4K monitor and I already set my `mouse speed` to maximum."

1. Find your mouse device ID

   Press `crtl`+`alt`+`T` to open the terminal.
   Type `xinput --list --short`.
   Under `Virtual core pointer` section, you should find your mouse id.
   My mouse is `id=13`.
   **Note:** It changes when you plug your mouse into a different port.
2. Type `xinput --list-props <device_id>` (eg: `xinput --list-props 13`) to find the IDs for `Coordinate Transformation Matrix (156)` and `libinput Accel Speed (297)`.
   Mine are *156* and *297*.
   The default matrix is [1 0 0],[0 1 0],[0 0 1] (identity matrix).
   The maximum mouse speed is *1.0*.
3. Lower the mouse speed from graphic UI, while keep the terminal opens.

   Type `xinput --list-props <device_id>` again. If your `libinput Accel Speed (297)` lower than before, you are in the right place.
4. Change the matrix.
   Set mouse speed to maximum by `xinput --set-prop 13 297 1` (*13* is my mouse device ID, and *297* is my `libinput Accel Speed` ID).

   Since the mouse speed cannot go beyond *1.0*. Let's scale the position by change the x, y coordinates from the matrix.
   Try `xinput --set-prop 13 156 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1` (*13* is my mouse device ID, and *156* is my `Coordinate Transformation Matrix` ID).
   If it's too fast, try `1.5 0 0 0 1.5 0 0 0 1`. If it's still too slow, try `4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1`.
   Only change the 1st two non-zero value, keep the last one as *1*.

For full description on **input coordinate transformation** is [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation).

Comment: Thank you! now I can play starcraft!!! it should be a right answer, because acceleration is not a speed. it harms in games.

Answer (score 3):

For me the suggested solutions broke synergy mouse control which I am using to control multiple machines.

I accidentally found that there is another mouse setting in gnome tweaks which doesnt break synergy and you can set everything though a UI.

To install: (copied from https://askubuntu.com/a/966634/1100244)

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
gnome-tweaks  #  now launch it (alternative: press start button and type "tweaks")
```

In there go to "Keyboard & Mouse" => Mouse => Acceleration Profile. Change the setting from "Default" to "Flat". Enjoy your increased mouse speed ;)

Of course you can still use the normal mouse speed settings to fine tune the speed.

[Screenshot of Gnome Tweak Tool Mouse Speed Settings with Acceleration Profile marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SyK9.png)

Comment: wanted to change the image display but apparently im lacking "reputation" ..